# Limit and offset with a window function

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, window-functions, offset, sql-limit

Is there any chance that I use a window function to use a limit + offset parameters in order to have a result as a page ?

i.e I want to limit/offset by depname to show only 2 department, but all the rows where this department appears :

```
  depname  | empno | salary |          avg        
  -------- |------ | ------ |----------------------
 develop   |    11 |   5200 | 5020.0000000000000000
 develop   |     7 |   4200 | 5020.0000000000000000
 personnel |     5 |   3500 | 3700.0000000000000000
 personnel |     2 |   3900 | 3700.0000000000000000
 sales     |     3 |   4800 | 4866.6666666666666667
 sales     |     1 |   5000 | 4866.6666666666666667
 sales     |     4 |   4800 | 4866.6666666666666667
 tech      |     9 |   4500 | 5020.0000000000000000
 tech      |     8 |   6000 | 5020.0000000000000000
 tech      |    10 |   5200 | 5020.0000000000000000
```

I expect as result those :

**limit : 2 - offset : 0**

```
  depname  | empno | salary |          avg        
  -------- |------ | ------ |----------------------
 develop   |    11 |   5200 | 5020.0000000000000000
 develop   |     7 |   4200 | 5020.0000000000000000
 personnel |     5 |   3500 | 3700.0000000000000000
 personnel |     2 |   3900 | 3700.0000000000000000
```

**limit : 2 - offset : 1**

```
  depname  | empno | salary |          avg        
  -------- |------ | ------ |----------------------
 sales     |     3 |   4800 | 4866.6666666666666667
 sales     |     1 |   5000 | 4866.6666666666666667
 sales     |     4 |   4800 | 4866.6666666666666667
 tech      |     9 |   4500 | 5020.0000000000000000
 tech      |     8 |   6000 | 5020.0000000000000000
 tech      |    10 |   5200 | 5020.0000000000000000
```

Best I can do with Row number is this

```
  depname  | empno | salary |          avg          |
  -------- |------ | ------ |---------------------- |
 develop   |    11 |   5200 | 5020.0000000000000000 | 1
 develop   |     7 |   4200 | 5020.0000000000000000 | 2
 personnel |     5 |   3500 | 3700.0000000000000000 | 1
 personnel |     2 |   3900 | 3700.0000000000000000 | 2
 sales     |     3 |   4800 | 4866.6666666666666667 | 1
 sales     |     1 |   5000 | 4866.6666666666666667 | 2
 sales     |     4 |   4800 | 4866.6666666666666667 | 3
 tech      |     9 |   4500 | 5020.0000000000000000 | 1
 tech      |     8 |   6000 | 5020.0000000000000000 | 2
 tech      |    10 |   5200 | 5020.0000000000000000 | 3
```

So I can't limit and offset properly... Have you any idea how I can use window functions (or anything else but those seem to be great to group like this) to limit and offset on a group of value according to a certain column value.

Comment: I fail to understand how are you sorting the rows. A `LIMIT/OFFSET` use requires some consistent ordering. Why is the first case returning develop & tech, rather that personnel & sales?

Comment: My bad i didn't order properly my example. I edited my solution. I order by depname.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `DENSE_RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY depname) dr
FROM tablename
```

you get a new column `dr` which ranks each row by the column `depname`:

| depname | empno | salary | avg | dr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| develop | 11 | 5200 | 5020 | 1 |
| develop | 7 | 4200 | 5020 | 1 |
| personnel | 5 | 3500 | 3700 | 2 |
| personnel | 2 | 3900 | 3700 | 2 |
| sales | 3 | 4800 | 4866.666666666667 | 3 |
| sales | 1 | 5000 | 4866.666666666667 | 3 |
| sales | 4 | 4800 | 4866.666666666667 | 3 |
| tech | 9 | 4500 | 5020 | 4 |
| tech | 8 | 6000 | 5020 | 4 |
| tech | 10 | 5200 | 5020 | 4 |

You can use that new column to apply the limit and offset that you want:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY depname) dr
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT depname, empno, salary, avg
FROM cte
WHERE dr <= 2; -- limit : 2 - offset : 0
```

or:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY depname) dr
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT depname, empno, salary, avg
FROM cte
WHERE dr > 1 AND dr <= 3; -- limit : 2 - offset : 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=842e658ad2c54fc2ce3a2d6af48ae3af).

Comment: Nice and simple.

Comment: I focused on the `PARTITION BY` part of the window function... This works like a charm thx !